# How to simplify $\frac{\sin\left(s\right)}{\cos\left(s\right)-1}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am interested in simplification for:
$$\frac{\sin\left(s\right)}{\cos\left(s\right)-1}$$

With [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%20sin%28o%29%2F%28cos%28o%29-1%29) I know the correct answer is:
$$-\cot\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)$$

How to make this step by step?

Comment: What is "simpler" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fact that$$\sin(s)=2\sin\left(\frac s2\right)\cos\left(\frac s2\right),$$whereas\begin{align}\cos(s)-1&=\cos^2\left(\frac s2\right)-\sin^2\left(\frac s2\right)-\left(\cos^2\left(\frac s2\right)+\sin^2\left(\frac s2\right)\right)\\&=-2\sin^2\left(\frac s2\right).\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Using complex numbers, the expression is

\begin{align}-i\frac{e^{is}-e^{-is}}{e^{is}+e^{-is}-2}&=-i\frac{(e^{is/2}-e^{-is/2})(e^{is/2}+e^{-is/2})}{(e^{is/2}-e^{-is/2})^2}\\&=-i\frac{e^{is/2}+e^{-is/2}}{e^{is/2}-e^{-is/2}}\\&=-\cot\frac s2.\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$ \cos s -1 = -2\sin^2\frac{s}{2}$$

$$ \sin s  = 2 \cos \frac{s}{2} \sin \frac{s}{2}$$

Plug these two identities into your expression